# Changing Text background highlighter

Tags: javascript, html, buttonclick

So I'm trying to get the background colour **of each line** of my `id="highlighter2"` to have a yellow background when clicked so it looks something similar to this [image]

and when it is clicked, the button is replaced with **"Unhighlight them all"** button which unhighlights everything. I tried to define the onclick with the id but instead changes the background instead, what's the right way to do/approach this?

**Code:**

```js
function Highlighter() {
  var p = document.getElementById("poem"); // get the paragraph
  var p = document.getElementById("highlighter2");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

```css
#poem {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: silver;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="poem">
  <h2> How Many, How Much </h2>
  <h4> by Shel Silverstein </h4>

  <p id="highlighter2">
    <p> How many slams in an old screen door? </p>
    <p> Depends how loud you shut it.</p>
    <p> How many slices in a bread?</p>
    <p> Depends how thin you cut it.</p>
    <p> How much good inside a day? </p>
    <p> Depends how good you live 'em. </p>
    <p> How much love inside a friend? </p>
    <p> Depends how much you give 'em. </p>
  </p>


</div>

<button type="button" onclick="Highlighter()">Click to highlight</button>
<!-- Highlight -->
```

Comment: You should not add `p` inside another `p`, it's illegal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Paragraphs: the P element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

So, use some other element to wrap all the `p` element like `div`.

You can change the background color and text based on the text of the button.

To set the `backgroundColor` of all `p` element individually you have to target all the elements first. You can do that by using [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on the *NodeList* like the following way:

```js
function Highlighter(btn) {
  var p = document.querySelectorAll('#highlighter2 > p'); // get the paragraph
  if(btn.textContent == 'Click to highlight'){
    p.forEach(function(pEl){
      pEl.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }); 
    btn.textContent = 'Unhighlight them all';
  }
  else{
    p.forEach(function(pEl){
      pEl.style.backgroundColor = "";
    });
    btn.textContent = 'Click to highlight';
  }
}
```

```css
#poem {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: silver;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div id="poem">
  <h2> How Many, How Much  </h2>
  <h4> by Shel Silverstein </h4>

  <div id="highlighter2">
    <p> How many slams in an old screen door? </p>
    <p> Depends how loud you shut it.</p>
    <p> How many slices in a bread?</p>
    <p> Depends how thin you cut it.</p>
    <p> How much good inside a day? </p>
    <p> Depends how good you live 'em. </p>
    <p> How much love inside a friend? </p>
    <p> Depends how much you give 'em. </p>
  </div>


</div>

<button type="button" onclick="Highlighter(this)">Click to highlight</button><!-- Highlight -->
```

Comment: @ahlie94, you have to target all `p` then loop through all the element to set the style......updated the answer.....please check.....thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`document.body.style.backgroundColor` will apply your style to the body. Try this `document.getElementById("highlighter2").style.backgroundColor`

Or `document.p.style.backgroundColor`